# tcpdf prevent page break within a html table block

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-table, tcpdf

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this table break in row

I want to start new row in new page rather than current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue in an old project, and I am setting `AutoPageBreak=false` and within for-loop I check if the increment has reached a particular value, then I close the table and after `addPage()` continue with a new table.

Its not elegant but works in my case, hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

A trick from @Justin R. from this forum, add this code to every tr...

```
<tr nobr="true">
    <td> your contents here...</td>
</tr>
```